# MongoDB Update Multiple Nested Arrays

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to mass update a value in a nested document array in mongodb using PyMongo with the structure:

```
document-|
    events-|
       event1-|
          key: (1, 2)
       event2-|
          key: (1, 2)
       ...
```

For each document, for each event in events I want to check the existence of the kv pair UTM_coords_xy and if it does not exist insert the kv pair UTM_coords_xy: (x_coord, y_coord). I have got this far but its not quite doing what I want, any ideas?

```
db.update({"events.$[i].UTM_coords_xy": {"$exists" : "False"}}, { "$set": { "events.$[i].UTM_coords_xy": position } }, multi=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `array filters` will do the trick you you.

```
a = db.update_many({
    "events": {"$exists": True}
}, {
    "$set": {
        "events.$[i].UTM_coords_xy": position
    }
}, array_filters= [{"i.UTM_coords_xy": {"$exists": False}}])
```